# Can't connect to battle.net

Tags: diablo-ii, battle.net

I just bought a new copy of Diablo 2 and Lord of Destruction. I installed it on my Windows 7 (Boot Camp) and tried to play it. But I couldn't connect to the server (Europe). So I opened port 6112 on my router, but still no connection. The error message just says:

> Not able to connect to battle.net

So I disabled Windows Firewall but no improvement. Finally I downloaded the newest patch (1.13c) and tried it again. But still it is not working. Any hints on how to improve the situation?

Comment: Boot Camp means your run that on a Mac, right? Why not install it on Mac OS X then? You should be able to download the mac game client on battle.net with your CD keys.

Comment: Hmm maybe I should give this a try.

Comment: Although it should work on Windows just as well. Maybe it's just a temporary issue?

Comment: I don´t think so. I waited for hours between the various attempts and friends I contacted don´t have the same problem. Today I tried it at work and here it is running as it should. So maybe it is a problem with my router at home. But what else than forwarding port 6112 do I have to do?

Comment: You could try hooking your computer directly to your modem, and see if you can connect. This would eliminate the router. If you can't connect it directly, putting your computer in the router's DMZ has a similar affect.

Comment: Also note that Diablo 2 won't run on OS X Lion, since it's a PowerPC app and Lion can only run Intel apps. :(

Comment: According to [the Blizzard support site](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=21109) you'll also need to allow outgoing connections from port 4000, but maybe this is not due to your router but because of the windows firewall, did you check that as well?

Comment: you might also be interested in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/17108/88), i.e. does is work if you run it as admin?

Comment: I just browsed through this page: http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=21109. It seems you might investigate whether open port 4000 isn't also needed.

Comment: I always thought you just needed to open port 4112 or something like that.

Comment: All home routers that I know of allow all outgoing ports, they only block incoming ports.  You shouldn't need any incoming ports open for Diablo 2, so unless you are behind a corporate firewall, you shouldn't need to forward any ports.

Answer (score 1):

The official support page on battle.net is https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-connection-issues
and it suggests trying to connect to a different Realm - Europe, USA to see if that works.

The official networking settings page suggests ports 6112 and 4000 (TCP) for Diablo 2
https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-connection-issues

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens to those who were trying to connect to Battle.net with a pirated copy of the game. You may have tried to connect to B.net with a bogus CD-key, which automatically (after several attempts) temporarily bans your IP address and/or account for some time, with each consequent attempt before the temp ban expires up to 2 weeks.

I once got myself into that very kind of trouble and tech support told me about the 2 weeks temp ban. I was so upset to find out I had to wait almost 15 days to play after I'd just finally purchased a 100% legit CDs!

So be careful not to accidentally click the Battle.net button with bad CD-keys prior to installing a legit copy of the game. This temp ban will also "spread" to any accounts you may try to log in with, and don't try to log in with legit CD key and a clean account from that IP until the temp ban expires! Better just switch everything if you're so willing to play this good old game right this instant.