# How can I run Diablo 3 without an administrator account?

Tags: diablo-iii

Diablo 3 appears to require an administrator account to run, but I'd like to run it as an unprivileged user. Can it be done? If so, how?

---

I have tried to run it from a portable hard disk, but it seems to add some files into the C drive which I don't have access to it. How can I overcome this? (e.g. make it add files to my portable disks)

Comment: If D3 works like most other Blizzard games, you can copy the D3 folder to any PC and just run it from the folder. But I haven't tried this, so I'll leave this as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Not that I'm condoning bypassing your school's IT policy, but it is possible to run Diablo 3 from an external hard drive/USB key, you'll need at least 8 gigs of storage space on the device (my install folder reads 7.77 GB. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67277/playing-through-an-external-hardrive

Comment: My guess is that the required ports will be closed. I mean why should they be open anyways?

Comment: @ayckoster well, unless the staff intentionally block them, they'll be open. it's an outgoing connection, so doesn't need access to be "allowed" at the router level, although it can be blocked.

Comment: Related question about the first Diablo: [Diablo requires “Run as Administrator” to connect to battle.net](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/diablo-requires-run-as-administrator-to-connect-to-battle-net)

Comment: IT Staff won't intentionally block the port unless it gets used for malicious purposes or is severely affecting the network in some way.

Answer (score 2):

**You'll have a few hurdles to overcome as a limited user, here are the potential ones and their workaround if applicable:**

**Problem:** Cannot install the program

**Work-around:** [Install on external media, plug into system, play from there](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67277/playing-through-an-external-hardrive)

**Issues:** Degraded performance due to the speed of the connection between device and system-bus, ability of graphics hardware, ability of host RAM and CPU.

---

**Problem:** Cannot run executables outside those specifically allowed.

**Work-around:** None without system intrusion.

**Issues:** If the computer has policy settings that only allow certain executable files to be run, then even if D3 is installed on external media, the OS will not allow it to be run. Many public computing environments block executables from removable media to cut down on viruses being carried in and installed.

---

**Problem:** Ports needed by D3 are blocked or firewalled.

**Work-around:** Remote Desktop to PC with privileges or Proxy server.

**Issues:** Those two solutions will only work if they are allowed by IT administration. Quite often, this is not the case in high security environments, as Remote Desktop is considered a security risk. Also, performance through Remote Desktop will be terrible without a very fast connection. In a work environment, use of a proxy server can often get you fired.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : This answer is more relevant to [the original form of the question, seen here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/69515/revisions). For the more general answer about permissions, see my other answer below.

As an IT administrator who works for a college, I'm going to give you a few harsh realities that probably apply to your college like they do at mine.

**You will not be able to install any software without an administrator privilaged account.** This is a group policy setting within Windows (I'm assuming you're using a Windows OS) that most any controlled computing environment will employ.

Even if you did succeed in installing it somehow, one of the following conditions will probably be true:

- Typcially, Computer Lab machines have a nightly process that they run
  to re-image a machine and bring it back to ITs default settings. **This
  will wipe out anything that is on there that is not supposed to be,
  without fail.**
- The computers in the lab probably do not have the necessary graphics
  hardware. The only exception may be if it is some sort of design lab
- Your college's IT division will see constant and substantial activity
  on the particular ports that the game uses and shut them down.

Also, I would reccomend that you don't attempt this. If you were caught installing unauthorized software on university owned computers you could face disciplinary action such as suspension or even expulsion.

**It just isn't worth all this hassle, is what I'm saying.**

Comment: +1 - just don't do it.  If you think they'd be okay with it, *you should just ask somebody to do it for you*.

Comment: This is completely irrelevant: he's not asking whether he should circumvent his computer lab's policies. Specific described situation aside, asking how to run a game without an administrator account is a reasonable and legitimate request.

Comment: He specifically asked about whether he could install it on a computer in a university owned computer lab. I gave him a direct answer to that. Through your convenient editing however, now 85% of my answer doesn't make that much sense, but the first bolded statement of "You will not be able to install any software without an administrator privileged account" is completely true regardless of his specific situation.

Comment: @Tater596 Mark's got a point; you weren't addressing the actual issue.  You just told him not to do it.

Comment: @Tater596 No, he didn't. He asked how he could play the game without an administrator account, and provided context for why he wanted to do that. Whether or not his specific reasons for doing so are acceptable to you, playing games without administrator access [is a thing people do](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=administrator) for legitimate reasons. Answer the question, not the person's motivations for asking it.

Comment: Well I can't exactly read what he said to begin with now that you totally changed it now can I? I can't remember off the top of my head whether he said "install" or "play". He cannot INSTALL a game on a lab hard drive without administrator privileges. If he brings it on a flash drive and can get it to run satisfactorily from there, whatever, but he can't install it.

Comment: @Tater596 You can see the revisions on the question by clicking [the link at the bottom](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/69515/revisions): "I want run Diablo 3 on the college lab computer. But I don't have an administrator account. Could anyone tell me how can I run Diablo 3 without an administrator account? Thank you."

Comment: @Tater596 Forget the fact it was about a computer lab: it's a red herring. Telling people it's impossible because IT staff will wipe machines every 24 hours is completely useless to someone who doesn't want to run a game on their home computer as an administrator for security reasons, or a cyber café that explicitly wants to allow Diablo 3 to be played by customers, or a family that shares a computer.

Comment: @Mark - I still don't see why my answer is "completely irrelevant" (thanks for the link to the original, btw) he is asking about university computer labs, I gave him an answer based on my experience on the matter. Every university worth it's salt has policies against doing what he is trying to do. Installing it on an external drive and running it from there will not excuse him from likely disciplinary action if he is caught. I'm just letting him know the likely consequences and why he cannot install it on the lab's hard drive.

Comment: And, on that note, this is why we can up and down vote answers. If mine wasn't direct enough, write a better one.

Comment: @Tater596 Again, he's not asking if he will get in trouble, and you have no idea what policies his university has in place. Have you tried yourself to install Diablo 3 as an unprivileged user? Can you speak to that instead of your speculation about his school's IT policies?

Comment: @Mark - No, I have not tried to install D3 as a limited account. However, having spent a big chunk of my career working in this environment, I feel qualified to answer the question. Installing programs is a group policy setting in Windows through Configuration Manager. He is locked out of that. He probably is not locked from accessing an external drive via USB. He can install it on there and try to play from there. Performance will suffer because of the USB connection and the likely case that the computer's graphic hardware is not up to snuff.

Comment: You can find my non-university specific answer below.

Comment: @Tater596 I have tried to run it from a portable hard disk, but it requires to add some files into C: drive which I don't have access to it.